# Prove/Disprove series converge

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can you give a hint how can I prove/disprove this:

If there is $x\in R$ that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_nx^{n}$ is divergent then the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty n^{n}a_nx^{n}$ converges only for $x=0$.

Thanks!

Comment: HINT: Let $x,x_0$ be fix and $x$ different from $0$, then $|x_0|\leq |nx|$ for $n$ big enough... I leave the details to you. It is a proof by contradiction